# Add fadeIn/fadeOut to add/remove class

Tags: jquery, css, fadein, fade, fadeout

The below code changes the orientation of my navigation by adding/removing a class name. How can I make it fade in and out when the orientation occurs? Here's my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    ($("#another-reason-to-attend").offset().top <= window.pageYOffset) ? $("#prim").addClass("horizontal") : $("#prim").removeClass("horizontal");
    ($("#another-reason-to-attend").offset().top <= window.pageYOffset) ? $("#logo").addClass("small") : $("#logo").removeClass("small");
});
```

**EDIT**

I've tried adding .fadeIn and .fadeOut to the lines above but it just breaks.

Example:

```
 ($("#another-reason-to-attend").offset().top <= window.pageYOffset) ? $("#prim").addClass.fadeIn("horizontal") : $("#prim").removeClass.fadeOut("horizontal");
```

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Answer (score 0):

not sure what are you trying to fadeIn and fadeOut.. asuming this is what you want

try this

```
 ($("#another-reason-to-attend").offset().top <= window.pageYOffset) ? $("#prim").addClass("horizontal").hide().fadeIn() : $("#prim").removeClass("horizontal").fadeOut();
  ...
```

since fadeIn() works only for hidden elements, hide it  is first(if not  hidden  )

Comment: I'm trying to fade in #prim and #logo

Comment: if your are trying to fadeIn after adding the class.. then above answer should work..

Comment: Yes it does but because its within a scroll function, the elements keeping hiding and showing depending if you scroll or not